# How do I set a value in CKEditor with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am wondering how I can set a value in `CKEditor` using Javascript?

I have tried the following, but neither of them work...

```
document.[form name].[textarea name].value=data;
$('#textareaID').val(data);
```

However, both these work without the editor applied. Is there a way I can do this with the editor?

Comment: I ran into this same issue again, 17 months later. Can there be a "Rediscovered I've Answered This Question Long Ago. Thanks, Me" badge?

Answer (score 111):

Use the CKEditor method [`setData()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-setData):

```
CKEDITOR.instances[**fieldname**].setData(**your data**)
```

Comment: Thanks your code is working But i put CKEDITOR.instances.**ckeditorname**.setData(**yourdata**)

Comment: documentation [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-setData)

Comment: I add to replace **ckeditorname** with the id of the textarea being rendered as the CkEditor. For example: JavaScript: CKEDITOR.instances["my-content"].setData("<p>Hello World</p>");  HTML: <textarea id="my-content" cols="80" name="profile" rows="10"></textarea>

Comment: Is there any way to do this in React JSX with properties? e.g. <CKE className="", value={prefilledData}></CKE> ?

Answer (score 34):

The `insertHtml()` and `insertText()` methods will insert data into the editor window, adding to whatever is there already.

However, to replace the entire editor content, use [`setData()`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setData).

Answer (score 13):

Use [insertHtml()](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#insertHtml) or [insertText()](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#insertText) method.

Comment: These insert new stuff at the position of the caret. `setData()` replaces entire content.

Answer (score 13):

Try This

```
CKEDITOR.instances['textareaId'].setData(value);
```

Answer (score 8):

I have used the below code and it is working fine as describing->

```
CKEDITOR.instances.mail_msg.insertText(obj["template"]);
```

Here->
`CKEDITOR`       ->Your editor Name,
`mail_msg`       -> Id of your textarea(to which u bind the ckeditor),
`obj["template"]`->is the value that u want to bind

Comment: Doesn't work. This does: CKEDITOR.instances.taCKEDITOR_Email.setData('<b><h1>testing</h1></b>')

Comment: @FrenkyB, how do you convert raw HTML text to Rich text when setData() is used in CKEDITOR?

Answer (score 8):

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1">This is sample text</textarea>

<div id="trackingDiv" ></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

</script>
```

Let try this..

**Update :**

To set data :

Create instance First::

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'];
```

Then,

```
editor.setData('your data');
```

or

```
editor.insertHtml('your html data');
```

or

```
editor.insertText('your text data');
```

And Retrieve data from your editor::

```
editor.getData();
```

If change the particular para HTML data in CKEditor.

```
var html = $(editor.editable.$);
$('#id_of_para',html).html('your html data');
```

These are the possible ways that I know in CKEditor

Answer (score 6):

As now to day CKEditor 4+ launched we have to use it.[ekeditor 4 setData documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-setData)

```
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(value);
```

Where `editor1` is textarea **Id**.

Old methods such as `insertHtml('html data')` and `insertText('text data')` also works fine.

and to get data use

```
var ckdata =  CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
```

[Ckedtor 4 documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_savedata.html)

Comment: I did not find CKEDITOR instance in browser console, but I finally find it in the `window.CKEDITOR`

Comment: @QiushiHuang, you can't find it on browser console but it works fine, and I think answer is for appropriate question not how to find instance.

Answer (score 3):

Sets the editor data. The data must be provided in the raw format (HTML).
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData( 'Put your Data.' );
[refer this page](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setData)

Comment: thanx bro this is useful fir me.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and worked for me.

```js
success: function (response) {
    document.getElementById('packageItems').value = response.package_items;

    ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#packageItems'), {
        removePlugins: ['dragdrop']
    })
    .then(function (editor) {
        editor.setData(response.package_items);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Take care to strip out newlines from any string you pass to `setData().` Otherwise an exception gets thrown.

Also note that even if you do that, then subsequently get that data again using `getData(),` CKEditor puts the line breaks back in.