# CKEditor load with value to edit

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

What I'm trying to do is load a page where I can edit my products. I want the current values to load into the CKEditor fields so they can be edited.

I would think this should be a very simple thing but I've looked and looked to no avail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610010/how-do-i-set-a-value-in-ckeditor-with-javascript

Comment: Do you mean you want to initialize with an HTML value or do you want to set it during runtime? If during runtime, Erics answer is just what your are looking for. Also, please share what you have already tried, such as the code that contains the "current values" and the code that initializes CKEditor. Welcome to SO! :)