# How to bring a response to a ckeditor ajax textarea

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm taking ajax response following a textarea and working properly, now ... how do I bring the same response to a ckeditor? since the ckeditor is an amount of divs simulating a textarea

AJAX:

```
var token = document.getElementById('token').value;
$.ajax({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        dataType: "json",
        data: {op: op},
        url:   ip+'/consultaObservacionOP/',
        type:  'post',
        beforeSend: function(){
            },
        success: function(respuesta)
        {
            document.getElementById('observacion').value = respuesta;
        },
        error: function(xhr,err)
        { 
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <textarea class="ckeditor" style="width:570px" id="observacion"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610010/how-do-i-set-a-value-in-ckeditor-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SetData` to update the content of the editor and then `updateElement`  to update the value of the actual textarea.

```
success: function(respuesta) {
           CKEDITOR.instances.observacion.SetData(respuesta);
           CKEDITOR.instances.observacion.updateElement();
        }
```