# How to insert a specific text into CKEditor image/link dialog URL input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

So, I use CKEditor 4 in my project, and I need to insert a string into the URL textfield in image or link dialog window (using js/jQuery) - i mean here:

[image: explain image]

I just can't figure out how to find some kind of identifier of this input element. I mean something like

```
var myText = 'abcdef...';
ckeditor.(that specific input field).val(myText);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you inspect those HTML elements on the CKEditor modal?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that CKEditor's elements id's are dynamically generated, eg. this element's id is 'cke_150_textInput' in this specific case. But it changes with number of previous textinputs, so basically when my editor's options change. Maybe that's some kind of solution, but it seems quite lame..

Comment: Have you checked this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610010/how-do-i-set-a-value-in-ckeditor-with-javascript ?

Comment: That's a way to change a value in CKEdited element, not in CKEditor dialog window text input (if I get it correctly)

Comment: Ok, I see... have you checked this on CKEditor documentation? -> http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.textInput-property-default

Comment: "This class is not really part of the API. It just illustrates the properties that developers can use to define and create dialogs." I think it doesn't help here. But I'm trying to modify link plugin to set a specific class / id of this input field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var newURL = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
var dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
    dialog.setValueOf('info', 'txtUrl', newURL);
```

Comment: At first it hasn't worked for me, but I made some serious mistakes using CKE in my scripts. Good thing is, I learned a lot just because of this situation. I'm a little bit late, but thanks a lot!

Comment: I've glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

After some time and with more experience, in my specific situation it was a lot better solution just to insert html INTO ckeditor at cursor, it's very easy to achieve with:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.your-instance-name-here.insertHtml("<img src='...'/>");
```

Maybe it will help you. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is what I made to set an URL into Links tabs on Dialog Image CKEDITOR

```
    dialogDefinition.onShow = function() {
       var link_href = this.getContentElement('Link', 'txtUrl');
       var link_selector = link_href._.inputId;
    
       if (link_href._.dialog.hasOwnProperty('linkElement')) {          
       link_href.setValue(link_href._.dialog.linkElement.$.dataset.ckeSavedHref);//set src img url
    }
}
```