# How can I take HTML code from a textarea and then serve that to the CKEDITOR as setData?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to take data from a textarea element to serve that as `setData` to `CKEDITOR` but instead of getting the HTML code I am getting the html code as a string, It's not being rendered as HTML code. Please have a look over the code :

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
    height: 200
});
window.onload = function() {
    var html = $('textarea[name="venue_description"]').text();
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor.setData(html);
}
```

Here is the result what I am getting as :

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a value in CKEditor with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610010/how-do-i-set-a-value-in-ckeditor-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `val()` instead of `text()`

```
var html = $('textarea[name="venue_description"]').val();
```

Comment: Thanks that's awesome. I can't even believe by only changing that the issue could be solved :P I didn't even bother to check that out before !